# How to FTP JSON data to a directory using Python?

Tags: python, json, ftp

I am looking to upload data to a directory once it has been created as part of a Python script. I gather FTP would be the easiest option, beyond that I need to know what imports and the best way to execute the code would be.

The JSON data is created using this code:

```
     mail = {}
       mail['17'] = {
       'box': mailbox
       'time': time
       'date': date
              }
       s=json.dumps(mail)
       print (s)
```

Thank you

Comment: What you have tried so far? Are you trying to do the FTP upload in Python and are wondering what module to use? Have you looked into [ftplib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html) for instance?

Comment: Thanks @GregSadetsky I have looked around and seen so many varied answers and conflicting views I was really looking for a starting place.

Comment: I shall look into ftplib